# How to fix serial-port transmission error?

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

I am trying to send some `chars` via serial port. The problem is that if I send `A` (`ASCII 65`) I receive something else (`ASCII 225`). Any letter or string that I send I receive something else.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <string.h>    
#include <unistd.h>   
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <errno.h>    
#include <termios.h>  

int open_port(void)
{
          int port;
          port = open("/dev/ttySAC3", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
          if (port == -1){
                perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttySAC3 - ");
          }else{
                fcntl(port, F_SETFL, 0); 
          }
          return (port);
}


int main()
{
          int port,n;
          char str = 'A';     
          struct termios specs; 

          port = open_port();
          tcgetattr(port, &specs);

          specs.c_cflag = (CLOCAL | CREAD ); 

          specs.c_oflag = (OPOST | CR3| CS8);

         cfsetospeed(&specs,B9600);

         tcsetattr(port,TCSANOW,&specs);
         n = write(port, &str, 1);
         if (n<0) {
              printf("\nError");
         }

         close(port);
         return(0);
}
```

I measured using an oscilloscope and that is the data leaving the device, so it is not a reading issue on my PC.

I searched the web for the last 2 days and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you receiving data?

Comment: From my device, a `tiny210` I have a serial cable to my PC where I use `Realterm` to read the data.

Comment: Check baud rate, flow control etc other parameters. Also, try `minicom` or `kermit`, before trying your PC side `C` code. The issue may be on microcontroller side code...

Comment: Are the 65 and 225 REAL examples? I was thinking the system might be  using bit 7 as a parity bit, but that would only affect bit 7. Your example shows bits 6 & 7 both being flipped.

Comment: @ JoeCullity Yes. If I send A I receive 11100001 and should receive 01000001. @ anishsane The baud rate is correct and also have tried other terminals and the outcome is the same. Also I think you understood wrong, I am sending from microcontroller to PC.

Comment: What's a "serial port"? Please specify which system this is for. I'm assuming Linux?

Comment: @alk Yes, that's what I want. 
@ Lundin [Serial port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port). Tiny210 ( the device) is running Linux, and at the moment I am receiving the data on Windows, but in the end the communication will be between Linux devices.

Comment: Other examples of what is sent and what is received would shed more light.  Suggest '0' (48) and and 'U' (0x55).  Also paired `chars` like "AA", "BB", "00, "UU".  ( I suspect 1 side is 7-bit and the other is 8)

Comment: But **is** the uP side set up to use this? You **cannot force it** from the outside by simply "talking" this to it using this setup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you get 226 for a "`'B'`" then I'd say the uP sends a `'b'` **and** uses **7** data bits **and** uses parity.

---

From *N Alex*'s comment below I conclude:

1. My above assumption was wrong.
2. He could have simply added a proper initialisation to the termios structure:

   ```
   struct termios specs = {0};
   ```

Comment: Yes, you were right. I changed the code and added  
        `specs.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
        specs.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        specs.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        specs.c_cflag |= CS8;` And now it works.

Comment: I think your assumption was right. I really did receive a `b` if on my receiver I used 7 data bits and parity.

Comment: @NAlex: Err ... but the code you show in your comment does set No Parity and 8 data bits.

Comment: Yes, that was the fix because I wanted no parity and 8 data bits, but the error occurred because I did not initialize the struct properly and it was using 7 data bits and parity.

Comment: @NAlex: Ahok, sometimes finding a solution goes winding roads ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Baud rate is one parameter, there are also number of data bits, stop bits, parity and flow control (RTS/CTS, none, etc). These parameters must be identical on both sides, provided the hardware on both sides support them. If this is the case, then the cable Rx, Tx must connect Rx(side A) to Tx(side B) and Tx(side A) to Rx(side B).

This is the minimum requirement if we ignore ground and grid for interference, and flow control pins.

The next consideration is distance. RS232 cannot go very far on standard cables due to interference from nearby static emitters (cellphones, motors, etc.)

The final, and imho hardest is that RS232 has no error correction. If some bits are changed during transmission, then the other side can only check if the packet is correct up to a very low degree, but it cannot correct it. For this, you'll need on both sides an error correction protocol, or at the very least a ACK/NAK mechanism in place.

Hope this helps.